# Launch activity from android browser on API level 17

Tags: android

I have a web service that provide a configuration file using a custom Mime type. I want to launch my activity using a intent-filter when the user click on the link. It works very fine on all Android Version, but in 4.2 (API level 17) it doesn't work.
This is my Manifest.xml

```
        <activity android:name="activityName" 
              android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
              android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.NoActionBar"
              android:exported="true">
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.xxx.yyy"/> 
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Any idea?

Comment: That should work on Android 4.2, assuming that something of your app had already been run on the device. You could try getting rid of the `nosensor` stuff and see if that helps. Otherwise, create a sample project that reproduces the error -- I'd like to take a peek at it.

Comment: I used the same code, the same apk, on real devices and on simulators, with the same results: it works with android version < 4.2, it doesn't work with android  4.2(.1). Tomorrow I will try to create a sample application (where I can upload t?)

Comment: "where I can upload t?" -- GitHub, a ZIP file on your Web site, etc.

Comment: You can download the sample project at www.sarbyn.com/TestMimeType.zip. The application try to download a file with a custom mimetype "application/vnd.sarbyn.config". The download will trigger the MimeHandlerActivity. It works with all simulator, but don't works with 4.2 simulator.

Comment: I will try to take a look at this later today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved,.
Simply add android:launchMode="singleTask" to the manifest. For some strange reason in android 4.2 the flag is mandatory.....

Answer (score 0):

Well, your app works on 4.2 hardware (tested on a Galaxy Nexus). It pops up the browser briefly (something I do not notice on a 4.1 x86 emulator, though it may be too quick). However, then control is passed to your activity.

My guess is that there is a bug in the browser as implemented on the emulator that is causing the problem.

That being said, if this really is for some kind of proprietary configuration file, I would recommend that you handle the downloading in your app. Rather than having people click on `TextView`-as-hyperlink or a `WebView`, offer up the list of configuration files in your own app and download it using `HttpUrlConnection` (or `HttpClient`) yourself.

Comment: Try the test application not only once. At first run it works....but the other click doesn't works. I tried again with a real device and with stock browser, chrome and dolphin: it does not work. Don't care about the textview link: this is a demo application. In the real application the link is delivered by sms

Comment: I have now run it ten times. It has worked ten times. The usability sucks, in that pressing BACK from your custom MIME type handling activity returns you to the browser (Chrome, in my case), and you have to us the recent-tasks list to get back to your `LAUNCHER` activity. My comment regarding doing the HTTP yourself rather than relying upon the browser stands.

Answer (score 0):

Just tested on Galaxy Nexus with OS 4.2.1. The test application does not work.

Opened a new ticket on code.google.com, waiting for feedback

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42409